# How can I set my webpack to configure sass-loader?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass-loader

I don't understand how to set up the sass-loader.  I have seen forums and nothing is working for me.  I want sass is recognized globally and I found sass-loader is a solution.  These are the version of modules recommended to do that:

[image]

This is the code of webpack:

```
    {
      test: cssRegex,
      exclude: cssModuleRegex,
      use: getStyleLoaders({
        importLoaders: 1,
        sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
      }),

      sideEffects: true,
    },

    {
      test: cssModuleRegex,
      use: getStyleLoaders({
        importLoaders: 1,
        sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
        modules: {
          getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
        },
      }),
    },

    {
      test: sassRegex,
      exclude: sassModuleRegex,
      use: getStyleLoaders(
        {
          importLoaders: 3,
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
        },
        'sass-loader'
      ),

      sideEffects: true,
    },

    {
      test: sassModuleRegex,
      use: getStyleLoaders(
        {
          importLoaders: 3,
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
          modules: {
            getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
          },
        },
        'sass-loader'
      ),
    },
```

The version of webpack:

[image]

Comment: Which is the version of webpack ?

Comment: The version of webpack is 4.42.0

Comment: So you are trying to outputting standalone *.css file on its own isn't

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post any errors you are receiving when running your build. Is that your complete webpack file?

Comment: I have a .scss global and I want the variables and mixins be recognized in any part of the application

Comment: The code of the webpack is without any configuration on my own.  I don't know how to configure it to achieve my scss be recognized in the whole application.